# Setting ListView backgroundColors after some action

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm basically wondering the best way to change the colours of the listview in android. Here is a basic explanation of what is happening, im getting the data for the list and populating it, then I run a sentiment analysis api against the text of the listview, in the onPostExecute of the sentiment gathering I then want to change the colours on the listview to be green for positive or red for negative.

I'm already going through my List of strings in the onPostExecute method and adding the values of the positive, negative and neutral like this.

```
                for(int index = 0; index<sentiments.size();index++)
        {
            if(sentiments.get(index).contains("positive"))
            {
                occurrencesPos++;
                      //ViewTweet.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            }
            if(sentiments.get(index).contains("negative"))
            {
                occurrencesNeg++;

            }
            if(sentiments.get(index).contains("neutral"))
            {
                occurrencesNeu++;
            }
```

Please note the commented out line will not work for me as it only works for the children which are the visible entities i.e. the first 5 but i have lists going upwards of 50 sometimes. However it does the required effect if I only search a list of 5 data items.

The list is being populated as follows: this is carried out in a seperate aSyncTask in the onPostExecute method.

```
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
       String[] from = { "name", "content" };
       int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(activity, list,
           layout.list_layout, from, to);
       setListAdapter(adapter);




    // Creation of content to be added to be displayed in list
     private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
       ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
       for(int i = 0;i<tweetContent.size();i++)
       {
       list.add(putData("@"+usernames.get(i),tweetContent.get(i)));
       }
       return list;
     }

     private HashMap<String, String> putData(String string, String string2) {
       HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
       item.put("name", string);
       item.put("content", string2);
       return item;
     }
```

So in short what is happening, grabbing tweets from twitter using api call passing the values into two string lists tweetcontent and username which are then used to populate the list, once the list is populated I call the 2nd async task which calls a sentiment analysis api, i put the results from this into a new string list and count the number of pos,neg,neu occurences to pass to a graph, but i want to update the list colors to match these positive negative and neutral values from the 2nd onPostExecute, is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Custom listAdapter? Also do u see if you set color for one item , it also set for other items ( e.g., if u set it will also set for 6th item) ?

Comment: Yes that also happens that if i set childvalue(1) then item 6 will also turn green I will edit the post now to show how i'm implementing the list

Comment: You have to use Custom ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an array and store colors of each item in it, and in get view assign that color as bg color.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely extend an `ArrayAdapter` (if you're not yet doing) and implement this logic in your `getView()` method. Managing *any* `View` content from within an `AsyncTask` is not a good idea because those are meant to handle non-`View` related tasks.

That being said, if you extend your `ArrayAdapter`, the second argument of that function, which is a `View` and is usually called `convertView`, contains the layout of each of your rows, so you can easily change its background depending on your `sentiments` value. For example:

```
if (sentiments.get(index).contains("positive")) {
  // Do whatever you need to do, and...

  convertView.setBackground(R.id.your_new_background);
}
```

You can assign any `Drawable`, `Color` or similar as your new background.

Comment: Updating a view from an AsyncTask is fine as long as it's on the post execute callback as that's on the UI thread.

Comment: That's right, but as I understand it it's ok to make *some* operation within the UI `Thread`, but **not** to process the whole layout of a `View` (I mean - it *can* be done, but it *shouldn't*), for this it's better to use some communication mechanism like `Handler`s.

Comment: How can i implement a getView method for the simpleAdapter I have already, lists would really not be my strong point

Answer (score 0):

Ideally i would like do this like this :

- datamodel which is passed to listview adapter is already processed by sentiment analyser and it has flags using which we should create views.I can set the color to required one in "getView" adapter method where "convertView" in  method arguments
  getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) maps to  the exact views which are available on screen

Comment: Would something like this work, if(sentiments.get(index).contains("positive"))
            {
                occurrencesPos++;
                              adapter.getView(index, ViewTweet, parent).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


            }      

Calling that paints all of the rows green must be doing something wrong in setup